# When I added the link tag and the routing, my react app stopped rendering anything

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

So I'm doing online store and I'm taking the project step by step, I was doing the navigation bar but when I used link tag and added the routing the react app stopped rendering, it's giving blank screen on the local host.

Navbar.jsx

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import './Navbar.css'
import logo from '../Assets/logo.png'
import cart_icon from '../Assets/cart_icon.png'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

export const Navbar = () => {

    const [menu,setMenu] = useState("shop")

  return (
    <div className='navbar'>
        <div className="nav-logo">
            <img src={logo} alt="" />
            <p>Books Store</p>
        </div>
        <ul className="nav-menu">
            <li onClick={()=>{setMenu("shop")}}><Link to='/'>Shop</Link>{menu==="shop"?<hr/>:<></>}</li>
            <li onClick={()=>{setMenu("mens")}}><Link to='/mens'>Men</Link>{menu==="mens"?<hr/>:<></>}</li>
            <li onClick={()=>{setMenu("womens")}}><Link to='/womens'>Women</Link>{menu==="womens"?<hr/>:<></>}</li>
            <li onClick={()=>{setMenu("kids")}}><Link to='/kids'>Kids</Link>{menu==="kids"?<hr/>:<></>}</li>
        </ul>
        <div className="nav-login-cart">
            <Link to='/login'><button>Login</button></Link>
            <Link to='/cart'><img src={cart_icon} alt="" /></Link>
            <div className="nav-cart-count">0</div>
        </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

App.js

```
import './App.css';
import { Navbar } from './Components/Navbar/Navbar';
import { BrowserRouter,Routes,Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import ShopCategory from './Pages/ShopCategory';
import Product from './Pages/Product';
import Cart from './Pages/Cart';
import LoginSignup from './Pages/LoginSignup';
import Shop from './Pages/Shop';

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <BrowserRouter>
      <Navbar/>
      <Routes>
        <Route path='/' element={<Shop/>}/>
        <Route path='/mens' element={<ShopCategory category="mens"/>}/>
        <Route path='/womens' element={<ShopCategory category="womens"/>}/>
        <Route path='/kids' element={<ShopCategory category="kids"/>}/>
        <Route path="/product" element={<Product/>}>
          <Route path=':productId' element={<Product/>}/>
        </Route>
        <Route path='/cart' element={<Cart/>}/>
        <Route path='/login' element={<LoginSignup/>}/>
      </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I tried multiple things to solve this when I found similar problem here but nothing worked actually

Comment: what error message do you see on console?

Comment: I see no overt issues in the code you have shared here. Are there any errors in the browser console, and if so, can you [edit] the post to include the complete error message(s) and any accompanying error stacktrace(s)?